# "apllication -defined or object oriented error" is throwing while compling vb code. working between multiple workbooks

Tags: excel, automation, vba

This is part of the code.

At the 1st if, an error popop is coming saying "application-defined or object oriented error".

```
For Row_num = 2 To 3

    'Column numbers
    For Col_num = 6 To 7

        'Check for grey color
        If Workbooks(Book_name).Worksheets("ParameterLifecycles").Range(Cells(Row_num, Col_num), Cells(Row_num, Col_num)).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217) Then

            'Check if software name is empty
            If Not IsEmpty(Workbooks(Book_name).Worksheets("ParameterLifecycles").Range("S" & Row_num)) Then

                soft_rd = Workbooks(Book_name).Worksheets("ParameterLifecycles").Range("S" & Row_num)

            Else
                soft_rd = Workbooks(Book_name).Worksheets("ParameterLifecycles").Range("B" & Row_num)

            End If

            'Exit the row once software name is obtained
            Col_num = 16[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to raise your content quality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Workbooks(Book_name).Worksheets("ParameterLifecycles").Range(Cells(Row_num, Col_num), Cells(Row_num, Col_num))` the `Cells`  are taken from the `ActiveSheet` and probably not from `Workbooks(Book_name).Worksheets("ParameterLifecycles")`

The error occurs because the source of the `Range` differs from the source of the `Cells`.

Use:

```
...
With Workbooks(Book_name).Worksheets("ParameterLifecycles")
 If .Range(.Cells(Row_num, Col_num), .Cells(Row_num, Col_num)).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217) Then
 ...
End With
...
```

Please note the dot before `Cells`. So you are sure that the `Cells` are taken from the same sheet as the `Range`.